# Is Swift on OSX different from the iOS version?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

I want to get the bounds of a CALayer.

On OSX I have to do this

```
let bounds = rootLayer?.bounds
```

on iOS, this

```
let bounds = rootLayer.bounds
```

and then to assign this bounds to another layer I have to do this

on OSX

```
anotherLayer.bounds = bounds!
```

on iOS

```
anotherLayer.bounds = bounds
```

why? is swift different on iOS and OSX? That would be awful.

On both cases rootLayer is set like this

```
let rootLayer = vista.layer
```

Comment: How do you set a value to `rootLayer`? All this stems from the fact that on OSX that seems to be an optional, and on iOS it's not optional.

Comment: in both cases `let rootLayer = vista.layer`

Comment: @AlexWayne - that is not the point here. The point here is that Apple should make the language equal in both platforms.

Comment: That's *totally* the point. The language is consistent. The platform APIs are not.

Comment: Swift isn't different, and CALayer isn't either. It might depend on how you created each layer. The `layer` class method is an Obj-C-only API which would have to be an optional in Swift since it could be `nil`. This is the same for both iOS and OS X.  `bounds` is also the same for both. Looks like in iOS you've unwrapped the optional CALayer at some earlier step so you don't need to force-unwrap `bounds`, but in OS X version you're still using the optional. How are `vista` and its `layer` property created/declared? Are you sure you didn't miss a `?` or `!` somewhere?

Comment: @mc01 - vista is a interface builder view. `layer` is a property of a view. It is not declared by me. The declaration of `rootLayer` is on the question. The code from OSX was copy/pasted for iOS but I had to modify the points on iOS to make it work. There is always someone voting legitimate questions they don't understand down.

Comment: @SpaceDog - I didn't vote anything down & understood exactly what you were asking. From what little code you posted there is nothing showing the Type declaration of any objects or properties - it's all inferred. As Alex Wayne's answer below states, if you'd been explicit about the layer's Type you could figure out where the optional is. That's the info I was trying to elicit from you. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: The layer property returns an optional in OS X because layers are optional in OS X -- views are not backed by layers unless you tell them to be. In iOS, views are always backed by layers, hence the method does not return an optional. Apple could make it return an optional in iOS (to unify it), but then you would have to unwrap something that shouldn't need to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift the language *is* the same. The UI frameworks and API's, are not the same, which is expected since since the UI paradigms are not the same.

I've got no idea what API you are populating `vista` from. But somewhere along the line, you have an API that's defined slightly different on OSX and iOS. On OSX `vista.layer` returns and optional, and on iOS returns a non-optional. When you find where that is, you can correct for it, and unwrap the optional there.

Lastly, implicit typing is doing you no favors here. If you change your `rootLayer` declaration to this:

```
let rootLayer:MyLayerTypeHere = vista.layer
```

Then you'll get a compile time error right here if the type is returned as an optional, since `MyLayerTypeHere` and `MyLayerTypeHere?` are different types.

Comment: thanks. Anyway I think Apple should unify that. You can have different paradigms under the hood and the language be the same. These small differences for things that don't matter is what kills everything.

Comment: The language is the same, the difference is that OS X and IOS use a different API. Views in OS X are only backed by layers when you request them to be, so getting a layer from a view in OS X can easily return nil, whereas the views in IOS cannot return nil for a layer.